# Is it possible to construct a date out of the calendar week plus year in oracle?

Tags: oracle, calendar

I have a column containing calendar weeks plus year as string, which was constructed in way like this

`select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01.03.2020'),'WW/YYYY') from DUAL`

which results in a string like

`09/2020`

Is it possible to reconstruct the date from this string?
I would not care if the date is start of the week, end of the week or anything else within this week.

Comment: Are you sure your input data is really `WW` (*Week of year (1-53) where week 1 starts on the first day of the year and continues to the seventh day of the year.*) or is it week according to ISO-8601, i.e. `IW`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WW` format code counts 7-day periods starting at 1st January so just get 1st January for your year and add the correct number of 7-day periods:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
  SELECT TO_CHAR( DATE '2020-03-01', 'WW/YYYY' ) FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE( SUBSTR( value, 4 ), 'YYYY' ) + ( SUBSTR( value, 1, 2 ) - 1 ) * 7
         AS first_day_of_week,
       TO_DATE( SUBSTR( value, 4 ), 'YYYY' ) + ( SUBSTR( value, 1, 2 ) ) * 7 - 1
         AS last_day_of_week
FROM   table_name
```

**Output**:

> ```
> FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK | LAST_DAY_OF_WEEK
> :---------------- | :---------------
> 2020-02-26        | 2020-03-03
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e37aadcfe5da71360af8374c36752318)*

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
with test (col) as
  (select '09/2020' from dual),
-- construct the whole year with week markers 
whole_year as
  (select to_date(substr(col, -4), 'yyyy') + level - 1 datum,
          --
          to_char(to_date(substr(col, -4), 'yyyy') + level - 1, 'ww') week
   from test
   connect by level <= add_months(to_date(substr(col, -4), 'yyyy'), 12) -
                                  to_date(substr(col, -4), 'yyyy')
  )
select min(datum)
from whole_year
where week = '09';
```

The `whole_year` CTE - for week 09 - looks like this:

```
DATUM      WE
---------- --
25.02.2020 08
26.02.2020 09        --> this
27.02.2020 09
28.02.2020 09
29.02.2020 09
01.03.2020 09
02.03.2020 09
03.03.2020 09
04.03.2020 10
05.03.2020 10
06.03.2020 10
```

which means that query I posted above, as a result, returns

```
 <snip>
 12  select min(datum)
 13  from whole_year
 14  where week = '09';

MIN(DATUM)
----------
26.02.2020

SQL>
```

Comment: I get a paranthesis error for your query (ORA-00907)

Comment: I don't (obviously). Which Oracle version do you use? See if `with test as (select '09/2020' col from dual) ...` helps (i.e. move CTE column name into the SELECT statement).

Comment: Oracle (ver. Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production)

Comment: OK, thanks, copying the code into my IDE was removing one minus sign. Now it works.

Comment: However the performance is too slow. I was not able to run it with my real table, which only contains 19 rows.

Comment: If there are multiple values involved, yes - that query should be adjusted (otherwise it produces way too many rows, as you noticed). Anyway, as you already accepted another answer, I won't bother.